# JasperReports Server: Input Controls error

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

My question relates to an error when generating a report.

In *JasperReports Server* created a Single Input Control Value but when you try to generate a report I get the error:

```
The server has encountered an error. Please excuse the inconvenience.


Error Message

net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: Invalid type java.lang.String for parameter SelectAsset used in an IN clause; the value must be an array or a collection.
```

In the preview *iReport* everything works flawlessly. I will put the value and generates a report.

Comment: Put your jrxml here and give some info about input control in server

Comment: Input control is a Single Value Type. In the query, I added:
WHERE
$ X {IN, resources.resourcename, SelectAsset}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you mean a single value by "Single Input Control Value" it should not be a collection. So

Change your `SelectAsset` parameter type from `java.util.Collection` to `java.lang.String`

Then redeploy your report to the server then try again.

Comment: Thank you. I also changed the query:WHERE resources.resourcename=$P{SelectAsset}